# How to save file icon image in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

How to save file icon image in windows explorer ?
Each file type has each image. How to save it ? Or where is the location image ?
I don't want use printscreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. First, if the program in question has an *.ico file within its folder, your problem is more or less solved.

The second way would be to determine where the icon is located - usually, it's within an *.exe or a *.dll file. In order to extract the image from that file, you could use a 3rd party software, such as [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) or [IconsExtract](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html).

Comment: And this is THE BEST ANSWER you're going to get for free !

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to use printscreen. You could try to use Snip tool. Type it in Search Bar to open it.

If you want to check the picture about, for folder, you could right click it and select Properties>Customize>Folder icons>Change Icon

[image]

Comment: No. I want to save the image icon.

Comment: Well, I’m sorry. I misunderstood. See the changed reply.